# Angular 2 number pipe gives blank value

Tags: angular

I have an angular input as below:

```
 <input
      #total
      type="number"
      [value]="data['total'] | number : '1.2-2'"
      [step]="1">
```

The data['total'] is a numeric property. I see blank data when I used the above number pipe. Also the data['total'] has value in it. Cannot actually understand why is it displaying as blank.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself`. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8p3lg

Comment: Wel.. It has to be a number, not a string (or any other data type).

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with `data['total']` .
Can you explain how you get data `data['total']`?

if you think problem some problem with the pipe you can try to check something like this to validate the pipe

```
<input
      #total
      type="number"
      [value]="2.3 | number : '1.2-2'"
      [step]="1">
```

Comment: it is neither null nor undefined and this data['total'] is coming via API